# Distance between two points of MULTILINESTRING using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, shapely, rasterio

I have a .gdb file on river network and need to calculate distance between points that belong to the same river. So I need to calculate distance for every section of the river.
I read .gdb file with `geopandas`. My CRS is EPSG:4326

In the file every river has a geometry cell that looks like this (numbers vary ofc):
`MULTILINESTRING ((9.662499999999682 37.324999999998845, 9.656249999999602 37.331249999998924))`

This is the solution that I came up with so far for one random river as a try-out:

```
river_geoms = rivers_main.loc[0, 'geometry']
if isinstance(river_geoms, MultiLineString):
    line_string = river_geoms[0]
    dists = calculate_distance(line_string)

def calculate_distance(line_string):
    points = [Point(xy) for xy in line_string.coords]
    distance_values = []
    for idx in range(len(points) - 1):
        distance = point1.distance(point2)
        print('Distance between points: ' + str(distance))
        distance_values.append(distance)
    return distance_values
```

I get the following distances:

```
Distance between points: 0.0058925565099126834
Distance between points: 0.0041666666668191965
Distance between points: 0.0058925565099126834
Distance between points: 0.01666666666667993
Distance between points: 0.00589255650986244
```

I can't figure out how to interpret these results and how I can calculate distances in meters.
I am a complete beginner to geospatial data and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is no consensus between libraries in terms of order of usage lat, lon. Shapely has converted lat,lon to lon,lat. In addition I added haversine equation to account for Earth curvature and transform results into meters. Mind-blowing that lat, lon sequence is not standardised. Here is my working code in the end:

```
river_geoms = rivers_main.loc[0, 'geometry']
if isinstance(river_geoms, MultiLineString):
    line_string = river_geoms[0]
    dists = calculate_distance(line_string)

def calculate_distance(line_string):
    points = [xy for xy in line_string.coords]
    distance_values = []
    for idx in range(len(points) - 1):
        point1, point2 = points[idx], points[idx + 1]
        distance = haversine(point1[0], point1[1], point2[0], point2[1])
        print('Distance between points: ' + str(distance))
        distance_values.append(distance)
    return distance_values

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 * 1000
    return c * r
```